# error: roots: inputs must not contain Inf or NaN (Octave)

Tags: octave, sympy, symbolic-math

I'm using octave to do symbolic computations and getting the following error.

```
>> p
p(x) = (symfun)

   3      2
  x  - 3⋅x  - 4⋅x + 16

>> roots(p)
error: roots: inputs must not contain Inf or NaN
error: called from
    roots at line 87 column 5
```

Since I am new to symbolic computation in Octave I am certain I'm simply using it wrong. How should the calculation of the roots of p be done in octave?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`roots` is a numerical procedure, you need to convert your symbolic polynomial to the numerical form understood by the roots function

```
octave:1> p = symfun( sym('x ^ 3 - 3 * x ^ 2 - 4 * x + 16'), sym('x') )
p(x) = (symfun)
   3      2           
  x  - 3⋅x  - 4⋅x + 16
octave:2> roots( sym2poly( p ) )
ans =
  -2.1844 + 0.0000i
   2.5922 + 0.7780i
   2.5922 - 0.7780i
```

I don't know if the matlab symbolic toolbox provides a symbolic version of `roots` or not ...

**UPDATE** To find the roots of a symbolic polynomial, use the `solve` function; this function does the same thing in matlab and octave (for symbolic variables).

```
octave:3> solve(p, x)
ans = (sym 3×1 matrix)
  ⎡                                    ⎛  1   √3⋅ⅈ⎞ 3 ______________⎤
  ⎢                                    ⎜- ─ - ────⎟⋅╲╱ 6⋅√249 + 135 ⎥
  ⎢                  7                 ⎝  2    2  ⎠                 ⎥
  ⎢1 - ───────────────────────────── - ─────────────────────────────⎥
  ⎢    ⎛  1   √3⋅ⅈ⎞ 3 ______________                 3              ⎥
  ⎢    ⎜- ─ - ────⎟⋅╲╱ 6⋅√249 + 135                                 ⎥
  ⎢    ⎝  2    2  ⎠                                                 ⎥
  ⎢                                                                 ⎥
  ⎢    ⎛  1   √3⋅ⅈ⎞ 3 ______________                                ⎥
  ⎢    ⎜- ─ + ────⎟⋅╲╱ 6⋅√249 + 135                                 ⎥
  ⎢    ⎝  2    2  ⎠                                  7              ⎥
  ⎢1 - ───────────────────────────── - ─────────────────────────────⎥
  ⎢                  3                 ⎛  1   √3⋅ⅈ⎞ 3 ______________⎥
  ⎢                                    ⎜- ─ + ────⎟⋅╲╱ 6⋅√249 + 135 ⎥
  ⎢                                    ⎝  2    2  ⎠                 ⎥
  ⎢                                                                 ⎥
  ⎢              3 ______________                                   ⎥
  ⎢              ╲╱ 6⋅√249 + 135           7                        ⎥
  ⎢            - ──────────────── - ──────────────── + 1            ⎥
  ⎢                     3           3 ______________                ⎥
  ⎣                                 ╲╱ 6⋅√249 + 135                 ⎦
```

Comment: Also there is a symbolic roots function in sympy. Not sure how you'd call that from octave.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin thanks. Your comment made me prompt this a bit more. I have updated the answer.